# Steps to turn On/OFF the light using custom skill of alexa

Tags: alexa

Please guide with the steps and program to turn On/Off the light using custom skill of Alexa as I want to use invocation command if custom skill. Please guide me as I am very new to this topic.

I have implemented the smart light control using the amazon smart light document.Coded in Lambda function and in Samsung smart light developer console using the client id and client Secret.

Now I want to add invocation command, so want to proceed with custom skill.

Comment: Hi Komal, as hardillb already wrote you need a different skill type for that. SE is not the right site to give a step-by-step guide. If you encounter a specific problem when implementing a custom skill you can ask a specific question for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Smart Home Skill API does not use the "Alexa, Ask ..... " syntax. It just uses the name of the device you want to control.

This is a very deliberate step, it makes for a much more natural way of speaking to the Alexa for control of devices. e.g.

> Alexa, turn off the kitchen light

It also handles all the entity extraction and translation for different languages for you.

If you want to use the "Alexa, Ask ..." pattern then you will need to define a skill using the [normal](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/steps-to-build-a-custom-skill.html) (Not Smart Home Skill) API. In this case you will need to use the tools to map out all the possible sentences that the user might use and flag the entities in the sentences.

This is lot more work for a way of interacting with a device and should only be done if you really need to do tasks that can not be controlled by the built in Smart Home Skill actions.